# Unit test HTTPServer creation using the Tornado framework

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I'm trying to unit test a Tornado application.

The goal of my test (`test_POST_empty_json_in_do_nothing`) is now only to send a POST request of an empty zipped json. When it receive the request the HTTPServer must only return an HTTP code 200.

Following [this example](https://gist.github.com/reinhrst/8775b63b1c369773e1f7) I override `get_http_server` to return my HTTPServer using the `make_server` function. As far ass I understand, in this way the test module will automatically use this server during the tests.

**test_main_server.py**

```
class TestMainServer(AsyncHTTPSTestCase):

    def get_app(self):
        return ecomtranslatorSrv.make_app()

    def get_http_server(self):
        return ecomtranslatorSrv.make_server(self._app, self.io_loop)

    def test_GET_main_handler(self):
        response = self.fetch('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)

    def test_POST_empty_json_in_do_nothing(self):
        headers = tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json", 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'})
        response = self.fetch(method='POST', path='/basket/json_in', headers=headers, body='{}')
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)


def main():
    tornado.testing.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**main_server.py**

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        pass

class NewBasketHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        pass


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (MAIN_HANDLER, MainHandler),
        (NEW_BASKET, NewBasketHandler)
    ])


def make_server(app, io_loop=None):
    return tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, io_loop=io_loop, decompress_request=True)
```

But doing this both the tests fail with:

> AssertionError: Async operation timed out after 5 seconds

So my first problem is: why this happen?

Of course if I completely remove the `get_http_server` function both tests pass, but Tornado also return:

> WARNING:tornado.general:Unsupported Content-Encoding: gzip

And that make sense, because I'm using an HTTPServer that does not have the `decompress_request` parameter.

I don't understand how can I use in the test module the HTTPServer returned by the `make_server` function, that is the server created with the parameter I want.

Putting it in another way: how can I test the fact that my server need the decompress_request parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the [issue](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2302) thanks to the help of the guys of Tornado.
I report it here what they told me:

> You should not override get_http_server() - if you want the
>   decompress_request option, you should return it in
>   get_httpserver_options()
>
> Overriding get_httpserver_options() is the documented way to
>   customize this. As you've seen, you have to rely on the private _app
>   attribute to override get_http_server.
>
> But why is it timing out? You're subclassing AsyncHTTPSTestCase - note
>   the S. This means that you need to create a TLS-enabled server, so you
>   must pass ssl_options to the HTTPServer constructor. Without that
>   you're creating an unencrypted server, which doesn't know how to
>   interpret the TLS handshake (and it doesn't contain the magic \r\n\r\n
>   sequence of bytes, so the server just sits there waiting for the HTTP
>   request to be completed).

So I created a new certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout test.key -out test.crt -subj "/CN=example.com" -days 3650
```

And used the files created by this command to create a ssl certificate. Than I pass it to the HTTPServer.

```
def make_server(app):
    ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain(os.path.join(CERTIFICATE_PATH, test.crt), os.path.join(KEY_PATH, test.key))
    return tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, decompress_request=True, ssl_options=ssl_ctx)
```